# Python subprocess call can't find full path on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

In my Python script, this line:

```
call("/Applications/BitRock\\ InstallBuilder\\ for\\ Qt\\ 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh")
```

will fail every time with the error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

However, if I write out the result of that string:

```
sys.stdout.write("/Applications/BitRock\\ InstallBuilder\\ for\\ Qt\\ 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh")
```

I get:

```
/Applications/BitRock\ InstallBuilder\ for\ Qt\ 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh
```

If I put that directly into the terminal, it works perfect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `subprocess.call` uses no shell (`shell=False`). Therefore, there's no need to escape the spaces. The space escaping is needed in shells (because shells need to know what's the binary's name and what the arguments). Therefore the following uses are all correct (and similar):

1. Without spawning a shell that spawns the subprocess (favorable):

   ```
   from subprocess import call
   call('/Applications/BitRock InstallBuilder for Qt 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh')
   ```
2. or again without shell (explicit `shell=False` and the usage of an argument list)

   ```
   from subprocess import call
   call(['/Applications/BitRock InstallBuilder for Qt 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh'],
        shell=False)
   ```
3. But when `subprocess` is told to first of all swawn shell which then spawns the subprocess itself, the spaces have to be escaped, because it's a shell command:

   ```
   from subprocess import call
   call('/Applications/BitRock\\ InstallBuilder\\ for\\ Qt 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh',
        shell=True)
   ```
4. An alternative would be to use a shell and quotes:

   ```
   from subprocess import call
   call('"/Applications/BitRock InstallBuilder for Qt 8.5.2/bin/Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh"',
        shell=True)
   ```

I'd recommend not to use a shell whenever possible (mostly for security reasons), remember though you have to pass the arguments to the command as a `list` if you're not using a shell.

Either (without shell, favourable):

```
call(['/bin/echo', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

or with a shell

```
call('/bin/echo foo bar', shell=True)
```

(both calls have the same output (`foo bar\n`)

Comment: Nice, thanks, option number 4 worked perfect, quotes, and shell. Security isn't a risk because it's a simple build machine that only I have access to. But thanks for all the information!